# Change JButton on down and on up?

Tags: java, swing

I overrided the paint component of a JButton, but now when I click it doesn't get darker. I searched google and stack overflow, but there doesn't seem to be an answer. So how do I make the button get darker when I click down and then return to normal when I finish the click?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    RenderingHints qualityHints =
          new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
  g2.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
            new Point(0, 0), 
            BUTTON_TOP_GRADIENT, 
            new Point(0, getHeight()), 
            BUTTON_BOTTOM_GRADIENT));
    g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
    g2.dispose();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet at the bottom works for me.  Here's how it works:

I check the button's model to see if the button is clicked.  When it is clicked, it paints itself differently.

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = buildFrame();
        frame.add(new MyButton());
    }

    private static class MyButton extends JButton {


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Color color;

            if (getModel().isPressed()) {
                color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                color = new Color(0, 0, 255);
            }

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            RenderingHints qualityHints =
                    new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            qualityHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                    new Point(0, 0),
                    color,
                    new Point(0, getHeight()),
                    new Color(255, 255, 0)));
            g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 10, 10);
            g2.dispose();


        }
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a need to register a `MouseListener` and roll your own `boolean` flag. Simply query the button model, as such [`ButtonModel#isPressed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html#isPressed%28%29).

Comment: @mre thanks for the comment.  I've updated my code accordingly.